# Trying to return a list of images with dimensions divisible by 64

Tags: bash, grep, imagemagick, zsh

The overall goal is to move any images that do not fit the criteria of having X and Y values that are divisible by 64 to their own folder, but I'm having trouble even detecting what images are have this value. Based off of an article on Perl Grep I tried

```
identify * | grep '{ $_ % 64 == 1 }'
```

but it returns nothing.

Comment: Perl's grep can test any expression, CLI grep is just for matching regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
identify * | awk '{split($3, dims, "x");
                   if (dims[1] % 64 != 0 || dims[2] %64 != 0) { print $1; }}'
```

Comment: It's vague:
    `awk: cmd. line:1:                   if (dims[1] % 64 != 0 || dims[2] != 0) { print $1; }
    awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error`

Comment: Fixed it, I forgot the braces around the block.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. All I had to do from there is trim the part in brackets off of the returned file names using awk.

Comment: I don't have ImageMagick, I based my code on the example at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php. It doesn't show any brackets.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
identify -format "%[fx:w%64+h%64]%i\n" *.JPG | sed -n '/^0/s/^0//p'
```

Please refer to [the documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php). Basically, I'm asking ImageMagick to output the sum of the modulo 64 width and height (so this is zero if and only if both width and height are integer multiples of 64) and I then filter with `sed` to only keep the lines with a leading `0` (and removing this leading `0`).

Comment: This is a nice and very simple solution. Thank you. The only reason I didn't choose this as the answer is because the other answer fits better with my intended usage case, but your solution is just as valid for the premise of the question.

Comment: @RyanHasse be aware that the other solution is broken for file names containing spaces...